# Creating an array that contains Class Module objects in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've an Excel file with three worksheets:
Worksheet(1) contains information of items from several brands
Worksheet(2) contains expenditures made on each brands
Worksheet(3) will contain general overview of all expenditures and earnings made through each brand

Worksheet(1) looks like this:
**| Column A    | Column B    | | Column C    | | Column D  | | Column E      | | Column F |**
| Brand Name  | Item Name   | | Item Option | | Net Price | | Exchange Rate | | Qty      |

- Column A ~ C remains the same while data for Column D ~ F will be added more to the right as Net Price, Exchange Rate and Qty changes every time.

Worksheet(2) looks like this:
**| Column A    | Column B    | | Column C    | | Column D    | | Column E      |**
| Brand Name  | Shipping    | | Surcharges  | | Customs Fee | | Exchange Rate |

- Column A will remain the same while data for Column B ~ E will be added more to the right.

I'll be using two Class Modules, one for storing Item Data another for storing Brand Data.

```vb
' *ItemData*
Private brandName As String
Private ItemName As String
Private Option As String
Dim BatchPrice() As Variant 'Product of Net Price, ExchangeRate and Qty stored into an array
 
' *BrandData*
Private Shipping As Double
Private Surcharges As Double
Private Customs As Double
Private ExchangeRate As Double
Dim itemBatch() As ItemData
```

In the main script, I'll read through Cell(2,1) to Cell (y,x), add each item information to ItemData then classify them accordingly to BrandData.

I've read that it's not recommended to put Class Module Objects into dynamic arrays. Is there an alternative solution?

I'm facing

> Runtime 91 error

```vb
Class Module ItemInfo
Option Explicit

Private brandName As String
Private Itemname As String
Private Options As String
Private netWorth As Double
Private arraySize As Integer
Dim StockPrice() As Variant

Property Let setBrandname(iBrandname As String)
    brandName = iBrandname
End Property

Property Get getBrandname() As String
    getBrandname = brandName
End Property

Property Let setItemname(pItemname As String)
    Itemname = pItemname
End Property

Property Get getItemname() As String
    getItemname = Itemname
End Property

Property Let setOptions(iOptions As String)
    Options = iOptions
End Property

Property Get getOptions() As String
    getOptions = Options
End Property

Property Let setNetworth(iNetWorth As Double)
    netWorth = iNetWorth
End Property

Property Get getNetworth() As Double
    getNetworth = netWorth
End Property

Property Let setArraySize(iArraysize As Integer)
    arraySize = iArraysize
End Property

Property Get getArraySize() As Integer
    getArraySize = arraySize
End Property

Property Get getPrice() As Variant
    getPrice = StockPrice()
End Property

Property Let setPrice(ByVal rawInput As Long)
    ReDim Preserve StockPrice(arraySize)
    StockPrice(arraySize) = rawInput
End Property


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    brandName = ""
    Itemname = ""
    Options = ""
    netWorth = 0
    arraySize = 0
End Sub
```

Class Module BrandItems

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Index As Integer
Private name As String
Dim BrandItems() As ItemInfo

Property Let setName(Iname As String)
    name = Iname
End Property

Property Get getName() As String
    getName = name
End Property

Property Let setItems(target As ItemInfo)
    ReDim Preserve BrandItems(Index)
    Set BrandItems(Index) = New ItemInfo
    BrandItems(Index) = target
End Property

Property Get getItems() As ItemInfo
    getItems = BrandItems()
End Property

Property Let setIndex(bIndex As Integer)
    Index = bIndex
End Property

Property Get getIndex() As Integer
    getIndex = Index
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Index = 0
    name = ""
End Sub
```

Main Sheet

```vb
Sub ReadData()

Dim srcsheet As Worksheet
Dim items As ItemInfo
Dim brandList() As BrandItems

Dim rCount As Integer
Dim lCount As Integer
Dim itemCount As Integer
Dim BrandArraySize As Integer
Dim BrandCount As Integer

Dim brandIndex As Long
Dim currPrice As Double
Dim tempBrand As String

Set srcsheet = Worksheets(Sheets(1).name)
rCount = srcsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCount = srcsheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'There are 700+ items that share identical brands so I'll sort them out'
For y = 2 To rCount 
    If y = 2 Then
        BrandCount = 1
        tempBrand = Cells(y, 1)
    Else
        If Not Cells(y, 1) = tempBrand Then
            BrandCount = BrandCount + 1
            tempBrand = Cells(y, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next y

ReDim brandList(BrandCount)
Set brandList(BrandCount) = New BrandItems

For y = 2 To rCount
    Set items = New ItemInfo
    
    For x = 1 To lCount
        If Cells(y, x).Value() = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        
        Call sortValue() 'This function fills up ItemInfo class'
    Next x

    itemRawPrice = items.getPrice()

    For Each productNet In itemRawPrice
        items.setNetworth = items.getNetworth + productNet
    Next productNet

    BrandArraySize = 0 'Checks how many Brands are in the List'
    
    If BrandArraySize = 0 Then
        brandList(0).setIndex = 0 'Here's where runtime error 91 appears'
        brandList(0).setItems = items
        brandList(0).setName = items.getBrandname
        BrandArraySize = BrandArraySize + 1
    Else
        For a = 0 To BrandArraySize
            If brandList(a).getName = items.getBrandname Then 'Since the brand already exist in the List, just add items to the array'
                brandList(a).setIndex = brandList(0).getIndex + 1
                brandList(a).setItems = items
            Else
                brandList(a).setIndex = 0
                brandList(a).setItems = items
                brandList(a).setName = items.getBrandname
                BrandArraySize = BrandArraySize + 1
            End If
        Next a
    End If
Next y
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with putting instances of a class into an array. Maybe a `Collection` is an alternate choice.

Comment: If its easy to write and easy to read, there's nothing wrong with using arrays. If you're looking for alternatives, the [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) Object is like a Collection, but you get to create a nickname for each item as you add it to the collection. That can help make the code more readable, and can make it easy to bridge between user input and your data. The user could select "Oranges" from a drop down menu, and you could directly search your dictionary: `myData("Oranges")` to retrieve the data.

Comment: Just to add to the earlier comments, I don't think you *need* to look for an alternative as there is nothing wrong with putting instances of a Class into an array, including into a *dynamic* array ... it's a perfectly valid thing to do